# lookup filters in CoreImage ~ iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, gpuimage, core-image

I am working on a photo editing application with GPUImage, There is an option in GPUImage called GPULookUpImageFilter. Basically it reads a color table and applied the colors to source image. How can i implement the same look up filter in CoreImage ?

Comment: "Basically it reads a color table and applied the colors to source image." Well not exactly..."GPUImageLookupFilter: Uses an RGB color lookup image to remap the colors in an image. First, use your favourite photo editing application to apply a filter to lookup.png from GPUImage/framework/Resources. For this to work properly each pixel color must not depend on other pixels (e.g. blur will not work). If you need a more complex filter you can create as many lookup tables as required. Once ready, use your new lookup.png file as a second input for GPUImageLookupFilter."

Comment: I don't know of any CIFilter that does this. Have you tried to make it from scratch?